# Use of 'the' before certain organisation names but not others

Tags: articles

Consider the following organisations:

- Hamas.
- Al qaeda.
- The Taliban.
- Extinction rebellion.

Is there a good explanation why 'Taliban' is usually preceded by 'The'?

e.g.

- What do Hamas stand for?
- What do Al Qaeda stand for?
- What do THE Taliban stand for?
- What do Extinction Rebellion stand for?

Other examples that I think require 'the' but I cannot explain:

- National Autistic Society.
- British Home Office.

Other examples that I feel do not require 'the':

- Action for children.
- Birmingham city council.

I have considered if [this answer applies](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/251291/141966) (among some other results), but I cannot find an existing answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking _the Al Qaeda_ would duplicate the definite article I think.

Comment: @mdewey interesting thank you

Comment: According to Wikipedia: _In American English, a "the" prefix is used thereby referring to the group "The Taliban" rather than just "Taliban". Meanwhile, in English language media in Pakistan, there is often no prefix used. Both Pakistani and Indian English-language media also tend to name the group "Afghan Taliban"._

Answer (score 1):

In the case of "Taliban", this is probably because "taliban" are students of the Koran.  But "The Taliban" is a [terrorist](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/67989/is-taliban-a-terrorist-organization-in-chinas-and-the-uss-eyes) organisation in Afganistan.

Similarly "Al" means "the" in Arabic, so perhaps saying "the Al Qaeda" would be odd.

There is no rule that clearly covers all cases. There would seem to be a trend that when the name is formed as "[modifying phrase] [group type]" (for example "[National Autistic] [Society]", then "the" works better.

> The national autistic society. The BBC. The RSPCA

But when the name does not include a word like "society" or "club", then no "the" is used

> Action for children.  Hamas.  ITV.

When the modifying phrase is a place name, you tend not to use "the":

> Birmingham city council. Formby Golf Club.

But exceptions to these "rules" are easy to find.  "Extinction rebellion" is an interesting case, because it's not clear if "rebellion" should be treated as a word like "society".  And I think you will find use both with and without "the".

Comment: I think an individual student is a _talib_ as _taliban_ is plural.